# Can I construct a jodatime.Duration object with milliseconds resolution?

Tags: java, jodatime

The API doesn't seem promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup:

```
Duration d = new Duration(millis);
```

Comment: I missed that because it wasn't in the Duration static classes and somehow the jar I downloaded doesn't include javadoc - Thanks.